Why am I getting this Rsync error on my MacBook?
I made a backup from an NTFS formatted USB flash drive to transfer files to a MacBook. For this purpose I created a simple bash script (I upgraded bash to 5.2 with homebrew):
#!/bin/bash

declare -A BACKUP_INFOS
BACKUP_INFOS=(
[/Users/<myuser>/Documents]="/Volumes/CORSAIR128/argomentare
/Volumes/CORSAIR128/articoli /Volumes/CORSAIR128/bibliografie ... /Volumes/CORSAIR128/xindy"
)

for dest_dir in "${!BACKUP_INFOS[@]}"
do
mkdir -p "$dest_dir"
src="${BACKUP_INFOS[$dest_dir]}"
rsync -avuz --delete --delete-after --progress $src "$dest_dir"
done

The file always worked until I upgraded my OS from Sonoma to Sequoia, but I can't tell if there's a connection.
Now the script doesn't work anymore and I get this error:
rsync: [sender]readdir("/Volumes/CORSAIR128/argomentare"): Invalid arguments (22)
rsync: [sender]readdir("/Volumes/CORSAIR128/articoli"): Invalid arguments (22)
300 files
rsync: [sender] readlink_stat("/Volumes/CORSAIR128/articoli /Volumes/CORSAIR128/bibliografie/nagel.doc") failed: Bad file descriptor (9)
...

I don't understand what this could depend on. If you need more information, please specify what is needed to understand better the nature of the problem.
Thanks
Update 1: I tried to set this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

But the result is always the same one.
Update 2: I set bash to be my shell and not zsh. However I receive new, different errors, with the above script:
macbook.sh line 3: declare -A: invalid option
...
macbook.sh line 27: /Users/<myuser>/Documents: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/Users/<myuser>/Documents")

Update 3: 1) <...> is just a sign of omission (and not part of the code): the directories planned for the backup are several dozen and therefore I omitted several of them in the code reported so as not to lengthen the text of the message too much.

I launch the script with
bash macbook.sh

ls -la macbook.sh returns the following simple output:
 staff 2106 22 Set 19:51 macbook.sh

If I run a command manually and referring to only one directory I get the following output:
rsync -avuz --delete --delete-after --process /Volumes/CORSAIR128 Argomentare /Users//Documents
1 file to consider    IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
sent 87 bytes  received 11 bytes  196,00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0,00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1358) [sender=3.3.0]

The mount point of the USB drive is (still) /Volumes/CORSAIR128

It's impossible to format on Sequoia in NTFS (that filesystem is read only)


Update 4
The problem is solved by formatting the USB device in exFAT. The script works regularly.
I wonder then if in reality the problem is (I formulate a pure hypothesis) in something that has changed in Sequoia with respect to the management of NTFS partitions.

Welcome to Ask Different. Could you add "set -x" right below the first line to increase the shell verbosity and see what is provoking the error? Also note that you are not using homebrew's Bash but the macOS built-in one because you specify "/bin/bash" (you can change the first line to "#!/usr/bin/env bash" to use the Bash binary configured in your PATH variable).

Thanks for trying "#!/usr/bin/env bash" and "set -x". I don't think "..." is a valid path specification, if you remove it from BACKUP_INFOS, does the script work? If it doesn't, could you add the output of the modified script (with "set -x") to your post? ("set -x" displays which commands the script executes and is helpful for troubleshooting.) You write that setting bash to be your shell gives different errors, that shouldn't be the case, how do you run the script (I mean, which exact command do you use to run the script? What is the output of ls -la script name?

It looks like the original error messages came from fairly deep in inside rsync, so if you try to do one of the rsync invocations manually, does that work? If that still errors out, we can ignore the shell confusion for the moment and concentrate on rsync...

@user41063, is the drive's mount point actuallly  /Volumes/CORSAIR128? You write this behavior started after upgrading to Sequoia, if you have a spare flash drive, could you format it as NTFS (on Sequoia), create a similar folder structure and a couple of dummy files and test it?

The script starts with #!/bin/bash so it gets executed with the old bash version which is part of macOS. Use the path to the Homebrew bash binary instead to make declare -A work.
